# NestJS Multer set dest to an url

Tags: api, express, file-upload, nestjs, multer

**Hello!**

So, when i upload a file with **nestjs and multer**, i want to set the **dest** in the **module** to an url, but if i do that, then it gives me an error:

```
 EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\Users\almak\Desktop\Chatenium2\chatenium-server\http:\localhost'
```

Can you help me why? Thanks, and also is there any way to **prevent nestjs** from **renaming** and **removing** the file **extension** from the file (`test.png => 03ebe1f47494378fee61196c0524afaf` )

Heres the code:

**Module:**

```
    MulterModule.register({
      dest: process.env.CDN_URL,
    }),
```

**Controller:**

```
  @Post("uploadImg")
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
  async uploadedFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
    return file;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dest` by default is a local directory for the server to access via the `fs` module. If you need to upload the file to another server from your server, you should use a different `storage` type.

As for the renaming of the file, that's also multer's default, you can pass options to the `FileInterceptor` [according to multer's documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage) to change how the file gets handled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what do you mean by "another ```storage``` type"?

Comment: The default storage types are `Disk` (where you write the file to the disk) and `Memory` (where no writing happens and instead server memory is used). There are other storages built by the community that can forward the file onto things like S3, GDrive, and others without custom service code